# Place the content within rounded corner box

Tags: html, css

What is the right way to place the content inside the box div with rounded corners so it wouldn't overlap?

[image]

Blue box is the content div which is inside the white box parent div. I want the header to be within that parent box so that it has rounded corners at the top as well.

When I tried "overflow: hidden;" on parent box, content (blue box) just went down:

[image]

```css
.WhiteBox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
  max-width: 340px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(118, 143, 255, 0.1) 0px 16px 24px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 65px auto 45px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
}

.BlueBox {
  background-color: rgb(50, 116, 186);
  height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: don't set a `width` to your containers and it should size to match the content within it.

Comment: you faced a margin collpasing that you fixed with oveflow:hidden ... so remove the margin-top from the header

Comment: Seems to work fine. You'll have to play with padding a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zdsqwoyh/

Comment: @isherwood here is his real issue : https://jsfiddle.net/zdsqwoyh/3/ .. remove/add overflow to see what is happening

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood. Apologies. (And he seems to be a her.)

Answer (score 1):

## Specific CSS Properties

If you want `border-radius` for less than 4 corners, then you need to use specific properties:

> ```
> border-top-right-radius: 12.5px;
> border-top-left-radius: 12.5px;
> ```

### Demo

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.wbox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
  max-width: 340px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(118, 143, 255, 0.1) 0px 16px 24px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 65px auto 45px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
}

.bbox {
  background-color: rgb(50, 116, 186);
  height: 35px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12.5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12.5px;
}
```

```html
<section class='wbox'>
  <div class='bbox'></div>
</section>
```